# java stack trace's line number mismatch with hadoop lib

Tags: java, numbers, stack, line, trace

1. I don't know the exact meaning of `<init>` function, why there is an `<>`
2. Actually there is no inner Class Conf in DFSClient
3. I trace the function flow, until DistributedFileSystem.initialize the line number is right, why top seven traces' line number not match with source.

Stacktrace:

```
[DEBUG] [main] |service.AbstractService|: noteFailure java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30s"
[INFO] [main] |service.AbstractService|: Service org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster failed in state INITED; cause: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30s"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30s"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLong(Configuration.java:1311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$Conf.<init>(DFSClient.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:92)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2687)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
    at org.apache.tez.common.TezCommonUtils.getTezBaseStagingPath(TezCommonUtils.java:87)
    at org.apache.tez.common.TezCommonUtils.getTezSystemStagingPath(TezCommonUtils.java:146)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.serviceInit(DAGAppMaster.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$9.run(DAGAppMaster.java:2662)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(DAGAppMaster.java:2659)
    at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster.main(DAGAppMaster.java:2464)
```

Comment: It should match the line numbers, unless you have some duplicate or other versions of the same binaries present in the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I don't know the exact meaning of `<init>` function, why there is an `<>`

The `<init>` denotes a constructor.  (If you see a `<cinit>` that is a static initialization pseudo-method.)

> 2) Actually there is no inner class `Conf` in `DFSClient`

You probably have the wrong version of the source code.

> 3) I trace the function flow, until `DistributedFileSystem.initialize` the line number is right, why top seven traces' line number not match with source.

You probably have the wrong version of the source code.

Comment: That's Right, tez used hadoop 2.7, while I deployed 3.0, so I just added 3.0's lib

Comment: Hi, stephen I used decompiled jar to trace , is it OK? there is inner Class Conf now, but the line number is not right.

Comment: The line numbers in the decompiled source code are unlikely to match the stacktraces.  But you shouldn't need to do this.  You should be able to identify the correct version and download or checkout the corresponding source tree.

Comment: @EricANi i have similar situation, hadoop 3.1 and Tez 0.9 but fails with same error.
Do i need to downgrade hadoop or I can do something for making it work in current condition?